# Execute Multiple JDBC Queries In a Defined Sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, transactions

I'm develop an application to connect MySQL via JDBC. In an action, I need to execute two queries, sql to read, and sql to update.

To make sure, sql to read query would be executed first, and sql to update to be executed later, I use JDBC transaction. But somehow, the problem is, mysql execute 2nd query first, and then the first read query.

Looking for suggestions. Many thanks.

```
            // Sql connection
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatementUpdate = null;

        String sql = "SELECT item_name, item_detail FROM Order_Printing where kitchen_id = ? and order_printed = ?";
        String sqlFlag = "UPDATE order_printing set order_printed = 1 where kitchen_id = ?";

        try {

            // Register JDBC driver (Note to add mysql connector jar file)
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            // Step 3: open a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false); // Disable auto-commit mode
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 4);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, 0);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            //
            preparedStatementUpdate = conn.prepareStatement(sqlFlag);
            preparedStatementUpdate.setInt(1, 4);
            preparedStatementUpdate.executeUpdate();

            int startingPos = 10;
            int orderNumber = 1;

            while (rs.next()) {

                String item_name = "Order " + orderNumber++ + ": ";
                item_name += rs.getString("item_name");

                String item_detail = rs.getString("item_detail");

                startingPos += 20;
                g.drawString(item_name, 0, startingPos);
                startingPos += 20;
                g.drawString(item_detail, 0, startingPos);

            }

            conn.commit();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
            }// do nothing
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you show what you have tried so far you'll have a better chance that someone will answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing rs.next() while loop BEFORE you call preparedStatementUpdate.executeUpdate();

Comment: Tried your suggestion, still mysql execute 'UPDATE' first, then 'SELECT'. That is not what I want.